# Unconstrained std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

I have an assignment to create a Test Bench for a N-bit multiplier. The code is odd to me.  It is a black box n-bit but for his std_logic_vectors he does not specify any size. Im guessing this is done with the test bench. I have not seem this before and was hoping someone could explain how this works

Comment: How what works?  Perhaps you could edit your question to show the black box interface declarations.  Throw in some indication of what your testbench is intended to test as well as a clearer expression of the difficulty you're having, supply context and ask specific questions.  Perhaps re-read the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and peruse the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help),  Try [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And please improve the title of your question, it does not say anything, except that you probably do not know much about VHDL (`std_vector_logic` instead of `std_logic_vector`).

Answer (score 0):

VHDL supports unconstrained std_logic_vectors.  This means that you can design a block that doesn't specify the length of the inputs and outputs.  There can be a number of pitfalls to doing this (see this [article](http://cdstahl.org/?p=361)), but in the case of something like a multiplier it can help with code reuse.  You get to define what the input and output widths of the block are by connecting them to a std_logic_vector of the desired width.
   Since you indicated that the block is a multiplier, I would check the documentation or interface to see if there are generics associated with the port widths.  That is a common way of creating a generic block interface with I/O specific logic inside.  That way you can specify how "wide" the logic needs to be, without having to have a separate block for every possible width.

Comment: You mention pitfalls.  The link provided above is now broken.   It would help if you enumerated them here.   I also see the converse where the generics are do set to nothing more than Data'length.   In this case, the generic is just busy work forced upon us by synthesis tools.